# Segmentation fault when trying to use SDL + GLEW

Tags: opengl, sdl, glew

I'm attempting to learn how to use SDL with OpenGL using GLEW for the extension methods.  As far as I can tell from pages such as [Using OpenGL with SDL](http://osdl.sourceforge.net/main/documentation/rendering/SDL-openGL.html) from SDL corner the following code should work

```
#include <glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>

#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) != 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (SDL_GL_LoadLibrary( NULL ) != 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 0, SDL_OPENGL) == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);

    while (1) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(50.0, 1.0, 0.1, 1000.0);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3f(1, 0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            glColor3f(1, 1, 0); glVertex3f(3, 0, 0);
            glColor3f(1, 0, 1); glVertex3f(3, 3, 0);
            glColor3f(1, 1, 1); glVertex3f(0, 3, 0);
        glEnd();

        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

However it just segfaults on line 12 when trying to call `glViewport`.  This is being compiled on OS X 10.7 with:

```
clang++ -g $(pkg-config --cflags sdl gl glu glew) -o test test.cpp $(pkg-config --libs sdl gl glu glew)
```

SDL is version 1.2.14 and GLEW is version 1.7.0.

Comment: Not a real answer, but maybe http://code.google.com/p/opengl-3x-tutorials-sdl/source/browse/common/sdlapp.cpp could help. In particular, you're not calling SDL_CreateWindow (but maybe one of your call implicitely does this ?)

Comment: `SDL_GL_LoadLibrary` is not needed since, GLEW does that for you. Your code works fine for me. Try compiling some other examples, maybe it's something wrong with your tools?

Comment: Please provide a backtrace. Also, information about the card, driver and OpenGL version.

Comment: @Calvin1602 your comment stands for SDL 1.3/2.0. SDL 1.2 have no `SDL_CreateWindow` and others - all is handled in `SDL_SetVideoMode`

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the projection and modelview sections outside the while loop and the glViewport after the projection:

```
#include <glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>

#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) != 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (SDL_GL_LoadLibrary( NULL ) != 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 0, SDL_OPENGL) == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, 640, 480);
    gluPerspective(50.0, 1.0, 0.1, 1000.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    while (1) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_FILL);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glColor3f(1, 0, 0); glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
            glColor3f(1, 1, 0); glVertex3f(3, 0, 0);
            glColor3f(1, 0, 1); glVertex3f(3, 3, 0);
            glColor3f(1, 1, 1); glVertex3f(0, 3, 0);
        glEnd();

        SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It cannot be cause of segfault.